# How to judge the repetitive data in the button events listview custom layout

Tags: android, listview

I developed a small project currently; I use the button events in listview custom layout, and add the data into listview. But now how to judge the data has added (how to judge the repetitive data?)

Answer (score 0):

1> Use the contain() method of the list to check whether the data is added in the list or not.

2> This function returns boolean. So using that you can prevent the repetitive data in the listview.